# What is intended fallback action for Firefox 3.x?

Tags: firefox, mediaelement.js, firefox4, firefox-3

Seems like Firefox displays a plugin with an "X" in older versions of Firefox (i.e. - any version below Firefox 4) and refuses to default to the flashplayer.

I understand that Firefox 4 is supported by mediaelement.js in that it can play ogg video.  What is the intended 'handling' of video by mediaelement in older versions that don't support ogg video or html 5?

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 is not an standard for old browsers like FF3.X. The options are:

- Update to FF5 (released a few days ago as stable).
- Put a flash fallback. This is a flash solution for old browser which not accept HTML5 format, but can play videos throught flash, like YouTube.

For more information about the second option, you can enter [to VideoJS](http://videojs.com/). This is a good plugin based on javascript to play videos with HTML5+CSS with a flash fallback.

Good luck.